# How do I use the ALT multi-edit functionality while emulating a 3 button mouse

Tags: modeling

emulate 3 button mouse, but i Select multiple objects at once，in the modifier panel, I couldn't use Alt + click apply modifier to multiple objects ,Where are the shortcut keys, please ，How can I solve this problem[image] ,

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you can use "Copy to selected" from context menu

[image]